# How to use Server.MapPath for Excel File

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel, server.mappath

Using Asp.Net MVC.

I have one Excel file which has default styles, borders etc and it's name is MyExcel.xlsx. It opens  "C:\Users\myusername\Documents" from my local.

Here is my C# code for it:

```
            Application excel = new Application();
            excel.Visible = true;
            Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("MyExcel.xlsx");
            Worksheet sh = wb.Sheets[1];
```

I uploaded my file to my Server 2012 like C:\MyExcel.xlsx. So i want to open server side MyExcel.xlsx file.

```
Server.MapPath("C:\MyExcel.xlsx");
```

But i get "Unexpected M" error. How can i fix this code?

```
>         string myServerPath = Server.MapPath("C:\MyExcel.xlsx");
>         Application excel = new Application();
>         excel.Visible = true;
>         Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(myServerPath);
>         Worksheet sh = wb.Sheets[1];
```

Comment: try putting a @ in front of "C:\..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting it like this:

```
Server.MapPath(@"C:\MyExcel.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Server.MapPath("C:\\MyExcel.xlsx");
```

or

```
Server.MapPath(@"C:\MyExcel.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the short code to demonstrate how to use Server.MapPath.

Before starting, please make sure that you have a folder ready in your Solution Explorer to save your images/files.

```
string img=""
string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/UploadFile/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName);
if (!File.Exists(filePath))
{
  FileUpload2.SaveAs(img);
}
```

If you run this code, you will find that your "UploadFile" folder in your project will have the actual file uploaded.

Hope this helps.